# What is use of having both state value function and action value function?

Tags: reinforcement-learning

I'm a beginner in RL and want to know what is the advantage of having a state value function as well as an action-value function in RL algorithms, for example, Markov Design Process. What is the use of having both of them in prediction and control problems?

Answer (score 2):

I think you mean state-value function and state-action-value function.

Quoting [this](https://www.quora.com/In-reinforcement-learning-what-is-the-difference-between-a-state-value-function-V-s-and-a-state-action-value-function-Q-s-a) answer by James MacGlashan:

> To explain, lets first add a point of clarity. Value functions
>   (either V or Q) are always conditional on some policy . To emphasize
>   this fact, we often write them as () and (,). In the
>   case when we’re talking about the value functions conditional on the
>   optimal policy ∗, we often use the shorthand ∗() and ∗(,).
>   Sometimes in literature we leave off the  or * and just refer to V
>   and Q, because it’s implicit in the context, but ultimately, every
>   value function is always with respect to some policy.
>
> Bearing that in mind, the definition of these functions should clarify
>   the distinction for you.
>
> () expresses the expected value of following policy  forever
>   when the agent starts following it from state .
>
> (,) expresses the expected value of first taking action 
>   from state  and then following policy  forever.
>
> The main difference then, is the Q-value lets you play a hypothetical
>   of potentially taking a different action in the first time step than
>   what the policy might prescribe and then following the policy from the
>   state the agent winds up in.
>
> For example, suppose in state  I’m one step away from a terminating
>   goal state and I get -1 reward for every transition until I reach the
>   goal. Suppose my policy is the optimal policy so that it always tells
>   to me walk toward the goal. In this case, ()=−1 because I’m just
>   one step away. However, if I consider the Q-value for an action 
>   that walks 1 step away from the goal, then (,)=−3 because
>   first I walk 1 step away (-1), and then I follow the policy which will
>   now take me two steps to get to the goal: one step to get back to
>   where I was (-1), and one step to get to the goal (-1), for a total of
>   -3 reward.